# Compute a LaTeX mathematical expression

Tags: java, regex, latex

How to compute a LaTeX mathematical expression using Java?

I have mathematical expressions which contains mathematical symbols like alpha, sigma, sqrt, exponent, etc.. , all these expression are available in Latex format as a string. Now How do I compute the value of that expression by using java.

For Example : The Mathematical Expression  [image: Quadratic equation]

is represented in a Latex format as a  **"\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}}{2a}"**   .Now I want to find out the value of that equation, the values for a, b, c will be provided at runtime. Is there any library?

Comment: Even that equation doesn't have any value... And regex does not _evaluate_ equations.

Comment: You realise that the majority of LaTeX strings aren't going to evaluate nicely, right?  I mean, LaTeX is a formatting language.